# Rails: redirecting to wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@trip = Trip.new(trip_par)

  if @trip.save
    redirect_to trips_index_path
    flash[:notice] = "success"
  else
    render trips_new_path
    flash[:notice] = "ERROR"
  end
```

When i'm sending 'form' from trips/new i got 'success' flash and it sends me to 'trips/index'path but i get view from 'trips/show'. I tried several combinations and it is still the same. My routes:

```
get 'trips/show', to: 'trips#show'
get 'trips/new' 
get 'trips/edit' 
get 'trips/delete' 
get 'trips/index', to: 'trips#index'
```

May it be problem with Routing/Action controllers or just my mistake?

Comment: To check if you have routing problem, check output of `rake routes` and see if you are using the right route helper.

Comment: Name your routes like this -> `get 'trips/index', to: 'trips#index', as: :trips_index`, check it here [naming_routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: Thank for help, but still not working.

Comment: Can you share the export of `rake routes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that "trips/index" is matched with "trips/:id" so automatically tracks me to "trips/show", because trips/id == trips/show. I add it manually so i had to delete these unnecessary routes, and it is ok. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks:

1. your routes.rb looks incorrect (not solving your point, but will save you time after): `get 'trips/delete'` should not be **get** but **delete**.

To make it easier I would recommend replacing the 5 lines of your current `routes.rb` by a single one that will do the job: `resources :trips`

All routing tips can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

2. Try placing **flash** calls before the **redirect_to**

> ```
> if @trip.save
>     flash[:notice] = "success"
>     redirect_to trips_index_path
> else
>     flash[:notice] = "ERROR"
>     render trips_new_path
> end
> ```

3. All your flash messages are `:notice`. Success should be `:success` and error should be `:alert` or `:danger` depending on the framework or convention you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your routes like this:

```
get 'trips' => 'trips#index'
```

or it's easier just to use "resources" which will automatically give you all the routes for index, show, etc...

```
resources: :trips
```

try appending rails/info/routes to your url in your browser to check out things like this

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes
```

look for your route in the list, or to make it easier to find you could make a custom route like this

```
  get 'trips' => 'trips#index', as: :custom_trips_index
```